# Tensorflow Resnet full-connected layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, resnet

I'm studying on the Tensorflow official example of Resnet (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/resnet/resnet_model.py), and I don't understand the expression of the last layer of its model:

```
inputs = tf.reshape(inputs, [-1, self.final_size])
```

where the final_size is equal to `inputs.get_shape().as_list()[-1]` if my interpretation is correct.
But for normal CNN model, the expressions of the last fully-connected layer are something like:

```
reshape = tf.reshape(pool2, [images.get_shape()[0], -1])
dim = reshape.get_shape()[1].value
weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[dim, 384],
                                      stddev=0.04, wd=0.004)
biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [384], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
local3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, weights) + biases, name=scope.name)
_activation_summary(local3)
```

And I have another question about the reuse of the model, is it only necessary to use get_variable() to initialize variables only when we use multiple GPUs?

Comment: The reshape op is the same as `tf.reshape(inputs, [batch_size, -1])` which basically flattens each image tensor to vector. `tf.get_variable()` is used whenever you need to use a variable more than once. For example, if you call the Resnet twice to classify a training batch and a validation batch, `tf.get_variable()` together with `reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE` will help avoid creating two Resnets.

Comment: @Richard_wth So it means that we can simply rewrite the reshape expression as `inputs = tf.reshape(inputs, [-1, reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, inputs.get_shape().as_list()[1:])`, right? But in the official example it doesn't use `tf.get_variable()' even it does reuse the model to classify the validation data, is it bc of the use of the estimator? Or basically it won't cause any differences in regard to efficiency?

Comment: Sry for the late reply...Yes, you may. However, since `reduce` is a python function, it'd be better to use something like `tf.reduce_prod(inputs.get_shape().as_list()[1:])`. The ResNet code does not explicitly use `tf.get_variable()` because `tf.layer` implicitly calls it and I guess `estimator` automatically handles the `reuse` part. I am not sure about the efficiency difference between `tf.get_variable` and `tf.Variable` but I think it marginal if there is any.